# Xcode "no profiles currently match"

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, app-store-connect

I wanted to distribute my app to itunes . I did the wizard on itunes connect and now it's time to upload my app . the instruction I followed says that I should change the Code Signing in Targets>Build Settings  to "iphone distribution" . but whenever I choose iphone distribution xcode says "no profiles currently match" though I have a valid certificate , and I have built a distribution provisioning profile . when I choose PROJECT instead of TARGETS , and change code signing to distribution , I don't get that error and it tells me "currently matches ..." 
I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this . 
thanks

 Edit: 
Short Answer : the bundle identifier is something like this : 43jklfsjdf.com.user.HelloWorld but you should delete the first part and change it to only com.user.HelloWorld in Info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have not changed your bundle ID in your Info.plist file. Check the bundle ID to match with your provisioning profile.

Comment: I found info.plist and changed the bundle identifier of the to my bundle identifier but I'm still getting "no profiles currently match" when I change my code signing

Comment: I have my distribution provisioning profile in my organizer , I have multiple distribution certificates in my keychain . I can choose my distribution provisioning profile in my code signing when I'm in PROJECT but when I'm in TARGETS it says "no profiles currently matche"

Comment: @smtabatabaie For your particular target, check which Info.plist file it is using under Build Settings.

Comment: when I search my project it seems there's only one Info.plist file and I change that . at first it's like ...smtabatabaie.${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier} and I change it to ...smtabatabaie.myBundle but it doesn't fix the problem. how should I locate the Info.plist file for my build target? tnx

Comment: @smtabatabaie are you sure your provisioning profile is for smtabatabaie.myBundle?